# Usage of linux system variable in the shebang

Tags: linux, perl, shebang

i try to include an external user folder with perl scripts to my general perl script. How can i use the linux system variable user (${USER}) to include these scripts?
I tried to add this variable simply to the first line of the script, but the variable is not resolved.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I /tmp/userSpecificFolder-${USER}/anotherFolder/AndAnotherFolder/AndSoOn
```

And the Output of this line is exactly what i wrote above, but it should be

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I /tmp/userSpecificFolder-CurrentUserName/anotherFolder/AndAnotherFolder/AndSoOn
```

Comment: Honestly, sounds like the user should be using the `PERL5LIB` env var

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've discovered, the OS's parsing of the command line is very limited.

How about:

```
use lib "$ENV{'USER'}/anotherfolder/something/doodah";
```

You might also find `FindBin` useful, because it allows you to specify relative paths based on your script location.

e.g.

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::RealBin."/mods_dir";
```

Comment: (y) maybe with the addition that there is no way to use a variable on the shebang line.

Comment: Bonus: This method will add any appropriate arch subdirectory too, where as `-I` won't